# php jquery ajax work with multiple forms and files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm not sure about the right title for this question.

I have two inputs with two buttons for them in `index.php`

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" name="input1" value="">
    <button type="submit" id="button1" name="button1" class="btn">Get Data</button>
</form>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" name="input2" value="">
    <button type="submit" id="button2" name="button2" class="btn">Get Data</button>
</form>



// display and insert them into database with third button
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    // the results goes inside these input
    <input type="text" class="form-control" class="results-container" name="input3" value="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" class="results-container" name="input3" value="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" class="results-container" name="input3" value="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" class="results-container" name="input3" value="">
    ...
    <button type="submit" id="button3" name="button3" class="btn">Sace The Data</button>
</form>
```

I want to get the input data separately and pass the values(ajax or `$_POST`) into two other files and do something with them in those two other files namely( `doing_somthing1.php` , `doing_somthing2.php` ) and get the results of these files and show them in `index.php` inside inputs(`results-container`).

**here is a preview:**
[image]

**index.php / AJAX Script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button1').click(function() {
            $input = $('#input1').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '.php',
                data: {
                    'doing_somthing1.php': $input
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                $('.results-container').html(result[0]);
            },
           });
        });
     });
</script>
```

**doing_somthing1.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
    $input_data = $_POST['input1'];
    // do other stuffs like foreach, if and etc..
    // and return new data in array
    $results = array();
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

I'm new to ajax and I don't know if I did this right, but if you understand what I mean and what I'm trying to do, please can you help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I've understood everything. But you do not need to use two files to handle the form. You can do something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
  $input_data = $_POST['input1'];
  // do other stuffs like foreach, if and etc..
  // and return new data in array
  $results = array();
  echo json_encode($results);
} else if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
  $input_data = $_POST['input2'];
  // do other stuffs like foreach, if and etc..
  // and return new data in array
  $results = array();
  echo json_encode($results);
}
```

How many inputs you want to submit to the form at the bottom ? You might need again a little bit of jquery 'on click' to handle the third form, because the inputs "results-container" are outside of it. By the way, you do not need the property name any more.

Comment: i'm not sure i can merge the files they have unique data and unique array results. and no need for iquery i put them in insert form